# Interactiv HubSection Header in Windows Store App - Custom Control or build in function?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, custom-controls

I am working on Windows Store App project usinc C#/Xaml. The apps main pages uses a Hub Control. Each HubSection has header. Some section use just plane Text but other sections should have interactive headers. This is no problem at all:

```
<HubSection Header="Plain Header 1">
    ...
</HubSection>

<HubSection IsHeaderInteractive="True" Header="Interactive Header 2">
    ...
</HubSection>
```

When IsHeaderInteractive is true the Header works like a button the interaction is indicated by a chevron in the title:

```
Interactiv Header 2 >
```

As far as I can see this the only way of interaction the SDK provides. But I have seen other section headers in other apps. Some use a chevron that does not point to the right but down to indicate that some kind of dropdown menu will open:

```
Interactiv Header 2 v
```

Other Headers show some kind of subtitle after the chevron:

```
LARG TITLE  >  small subtitle
```

Are these custom styles are there any SDK functions to get these other headers?

If custom styles are use, does anyone know how they work/look like?

Comment: I faced the same problem today.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you need to change the ControlTemplate for the HubSection. Right-click on the HubSection in the Designer in Visual Studio or Blend. From the ContextMenu choose "Edit Template->Edit a copy".

You receive the following Style that sets the ControlTemplate:

```
<Page.Resources>
<Style x:Key="HubSectionStyle1" TargetType="HubSection">
  <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="40,40,40,44"/>
  <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="HubSection">
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
          <Border.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="HeaderButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
              <Grid Background="Transparent">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                  <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                      <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="IsHeaderInteractiveMarker">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                      <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="IsHeaderInteractiveMarker">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                      <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="IsHeaderInteractiveMarker">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                  </VisualStateGroup>
                  <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                      <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"/>
                      </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                  </VisualStateGroup>
                  <VisualStateGroup x:Name="IsHeaderInteractiveStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="HeaderInteractive">
                      <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="IsHeaderInteractiveMarker">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="HeaderNonInteractive"/>
                  </VisualStateGroup>
                  <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FlowDirectionStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="LeftToRight"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="RightToLeft">
                      <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text" Storyboard.TargetName="IsHeaderInteractiveMarker">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="  &#xE26C;"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                  </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" OpticalMarginAlignment="TrimSideBearings" TextLineBounds="Tight" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                  <TextBlock x:Name="IsHeaderInteractiveMarker" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" OpticalMarginAlignment="TrimSideBearings" TextLineBounds="Tight" Text="This is the marker" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="-5" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="-5" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
              </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Border.Resources>
          <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Rectangle x:Name="HubHeaderPlaceholder" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <Button x:Name="HeaderButton" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" FontWeight="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderThemeFontWeight}" FontSize="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderThemeFontSize}" Margin="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderThemeMargin}" Grid.Row="1" Template="{StaticResource HeaderButtonTemplate}"/>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Grid.Row="2"/>
          </Grid>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Look in the ControlTemplate. There's a TextBlock with the name "IsHeaderInteractiveMarker". I've changed the Text to "This is the marker". Now the header shows this text for interactive headers instead of ">". You can just set the text to an empty string "" or exclude the TextBlock for your requirements. If you do the latter one, don't forget to also exclude the Storyboard-Animations for the IsHeaderInteractiveStates-Group.

And see the HubSection, how it references the Style with the custom ControlTemplate via StaticResource-Markup Extension. If you want the Standard-Behaviour on other HubSections, just don't set the Style-Property to the StaticResource. courtsey of Thomas Claudius Huber for helping me out.